# Наступить "в"/"на" капкан?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

Как правильно говорить: "наступить в капкан" или "наступить на капкан"? Я посмотрела на картинки капканов, они такие круглые, а спусковой механизм в центре, т.е., чтобы попасть в капкан, нужно наступить на центральную часть, внутрь круга. т.е. получается по логике "в капкан", но в интернете встречаются оба варианта, поэтому я не уверена, посоветуйте, плз.

Answer (score 7):

Я думаю: наступить на капкан (но при этом вовсе не обязательно попасть в него). А *в капкан* скорее всего попасть. а не наступить.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, можно и так, и так. Но, по-моему, "*наступить в капкан*" предпочтительнее. Это выражение можно использовать как в прямом, так и в переносном смысле.

"*Наступить на капкан*" - только если имеется в виду буквально. К тому же, такая фраза оставляет сомнения, попался или нет.

---

Заменить слово "наступить" на слово "попасть" - самый лёгкий выход. Но согласитесь, смысл фразы меняется. Не всегда такая замена уместна. Охотник, случайно наступивший в капкан - он что, непременно попался?

Comment: > "Наступить на капкан" - только если имеется в виду буквально. К тому же, такая фраза оставляет сомнения, попался или нет.
Вот я тоже из-за этого и засомневалась, ведь, если на край наступить, он не сработает...

Answer (score 2):

Сдается мне что в отношении капкана верно только ***попасть в капкан***.

Наступить "во что?" - уже режет слух. "Во что" можно только ***вступить*** (отдельные "авторские" исключения не беру в расчет).
"Наступить в капкан" можно, но не в том смысле, что в него попасть.  Ну т.е. когда он валяется на полу в нерабочем положении.

..----

Я не читал других ответов перед тем как написать. 
Получается, мы с Ларf расходимся только в оценке категоричности "наступления на". Она полагает, что при этом ***не обязательно*** попасть в капкан, я - что ***обязательно не попасть***. Вообще-то вопрос может оказаться гораздо принципиальнее, чем он кажется. Возможно мы по-разному этот самый капкан представляем. В другой теме я бы предложил все это обсудить, но здесь это не имеет смысла. Будем считать, что по сути ответа я присоединяюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте для начала разберемся в значении слова наступить. Наступить - 1.Придавить ногой кого-что-н. Думаю,говоря "наступить на капкан"мы уже машинально представляем ,что кто-то попался в капкан.Ведь на капкан надо наступить,чтоб он сработал.Однако,все же во избежания путаницы лучше использовать : попался в капкан.

Comment: > Думаю,говоря "наступить на капкан"мы уже машинально представляем ,что кто-то попался в капкан.Ведь на капкан надо наступить,чтоб он сработал.

Нет, Вы не правы. Если наступить на край капкана, то он не сработает, у него пружина срабатывает только когда наступаешь на центральный спусковой механизм - т.е. внутрь круга, который схлопывается, т.е. "в капкан", если считать "капканом" именно окружность с зубчиками.